Cauchy reduction formula with measure
The Cauchy reduction formula is
$$\int_{0}^{x}{\cdots{\int_{0}^{x_{3}}{\int_{0}^{x_{2}}{F(x_1)\,dx_1\cdots dx_n}}}}
=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}{\int_{0}^{x}{(x-t)^{n-1}F(t)\,dt}}$$
Consider a generalisation
$$\int_{0}^{x}{\cdots\alpha (x_3)~{\int_{0}^{x_{3}}\alpha (x_2)~{\int_{0}^{x_{2}}{\alpha (x_1)~F(x_1)\,dx_1\cdots dx_n}}}}$$
where $\alpha(x)= {\sqrt g}$ is a measure.
I wonder if the corresponding formula has been discussed in the literature?

Assume that $\sigma(x)=\int_0^x \alpha(x')\,dx'$ is invertible on $\mathbb{R}^+$, with inverse $\sigma^{-1}(x)$, then the following formula reduces the $n$-fold integration to a single integration:
\begin{align} & \int_0^x \cdots\alpha (x_3)~\int_0^{x_3} \alpha (x_2)~\int_0^{x_2} \alpha (x_1)~F(x_1)\,dx_1\cdots dx_n \\[8pt] = {} & \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \int_0^{\sigma(x)} (\sigma(x)-t)^{n-1} F\bigl(\sigma^{-1}(t)\bigl)\,dt. \end{align}
For $\alpha(x)=1$, $\sigma(x)=x=\sigma^{-1}(x)$ you recover Cauchy's formula.


The OP requests a test of the formula, for two examples:    
example 1:
$$F(x)=x,\;\;\alpha(x)=x^2,\;\;\sigma(x)=x^3/3,\;\;\sigma^{-1}(x)=(3x)^{1/3},$$
$$\int_0^x \alpha(x_3)dx_3\int_0^{x_3}\alpha(x_2)dx_2\int_0^{x_2}\alpha(x_1)dx_1\,F(x_1)=x^{10}/280,$$
which agrees with
$$\frac{1}{(n-1)!} \int_0^{\sigma(x)} (\sigma(x)-t)^{n-1} F\bigl(\sigma^{-1}(t)\bigl)\,dt=x^{10}/280,\;\;\text{for}\;\;n=3.$$
example 2:
$$F(x)=x,\;\;\alpha(x)=1/(1-x),\;\;\sigma(x)=-\ln(1-x),\;\;\sigma^{-1}(x)=1-e^{-x},$$
$$\int_0^x \alpha(x_3)dx_3\int_0^{x_3}\alpha(x_2)dx_2\int_0^{x_2}\alpha(x_1)dx_1\,F(x_1)=-x-\tfrac{1}{6}\ln(1-x)\bigl(6+3\ln(1-x)+\ln^2(1-x)\bigr)$$
$$\qquad=\frac{1}{(n-1)!} \int_0^{\sigma(x)} (\sigma(x)-t)^{n-1} F\bigl(\sigma^{-1}(t)\bigl)\,dt,\;\;\text{for}\;\;n=3,\;\;0<x<1.$$


Lots of extra curly braces in your MathJax code, that seemingly serve no purpose, may make editing cumbersome and set bad examples for those learning LaTeX and MathJax by looking at the way things are coded here.

@Carlo Beenakker: I tried to test this expression by two simple cases: (1) $F(x_1)= x_1$, $\alpha(x_1)= x_1^2$, $n=3$; (2) $F(x_1)= x_1$, $\alpha(x_1)= {1\over (1-x_1)}$, $n=3$, but both cases do not reproduce the explicit 3-fold integration computation.

@MichaelHardy, re, a surprising number of braces can be recommended as LaTeX best practice.  See, for example, David Carlisle's answer pointing out that official LaTeX document says always to brace one's arguments.

@LSpice : Do you mean you should write \sin{x} instead of \sin x? Or \int {{f(x)} \, {dx}} instead of \int f(x) \, dx? Or maybe {{ \int {{f(x)} \, {dx}} }}?

Math2024: I have added both examples you mention, which agree. Can I help you with a Mathematica notebook to check this yourself?

@CarloBeenakker Thanks! I found my error and I can verify it using the two examples.

@CarloBeenakker By the way, I wonder if you may comment on a variation: $\int_0^{x} ... \alpha(x_5)  \int_0^{x_5} \int_0^{x_4} \alpha(x_3)  \int_0^{x_3} \int_0^{x_2} \alpha(x_1) F(x_1) dx_1 dx_2 ... dx_n$.

you might want to ask a new question for that (we typically prefer one question per post and your variation is not a trivial one, I think)
